# C# Joins/Where with Linq and Lambda how to return a List<T>

Tags: c#, lambda

The query below works just fine and returns one `List<>` exactly as expected

```
List<purchaseOrderHeaderEntity> details = (from p in 
db.purchaseOrderDetailEntity join r in db.purchaseOrderHeaderEntity on 
p.purchaseOrderID equals 
r.purchaseOrderID  
where p.productID == productID select r).ToList();
```

If I rewrite it using lambda, it returns two lists:

```
List<purchaseOrderHeaderEntity> lambda_details = db.purchaseOrderDetailEntity.Join(db.purchaseOrderHeaderEntity,
                    p => p.purchaseOrderID,
                    r => r.purchaseOrderID,
                    (p, r) => new { Detail = p, Header = r }).Where(DetailAndHeader => DetailAndHeader.Detail.productID == productID).ToList();
```

If I remove "`Detail=p`" from the selection part, Join throws an error

> "The type arguments for method ... cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Is there a way to rewrite that query to make it return just one list for Header?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Thanks, haim770! That looks MUCH better as far as formatting goes!

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody! That is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

you can put the where condition before join, then you can return the r.

```
var lambda_details = db.purchaseOrderDetailEntity
             .Where(detailAndHeader => detailAndHeader.Detail.productID == productID)
             .Join(db.purchaseOrderHeaderEntity,
                        p => p.purchaseOrderID,
                        r => r.purchaseOrderID,
                        (p, r) => r).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query comprehension and your fluent query are different queries.

Your query comprehension expression is:

```
from p in db.purchaseOrderDetailEntity 
join r in db.purchaseOrderHeaderEntity on 
p.purchaseOrderID equals r.purchaseOrderID  
where p.productID == productID 
select r
```

Your fluent form is:

```
db.purchaseOrderDetailEntity.
  Join(
    db.purchaseOrderHeaderEntity,
    p => p.purchaseOrderID,
    r => r.purchaseOrderID,
    (p, r) => new { p, r }).
  Where(pr => pr.p.productID == productID)
```

But the correct fluent form is

```
db.purchaseOrderDetailEntity.
  Join(
    db.purchaseOrderHeaderEntity,
    p => p.purchaseOrderID,
    r => r.purchaseOrderID,
    (p, r) => new { p, r }).
  Where(pr => pr.p.productID == productID).
  Select(pr => pr.r)
```

Does that answer your question? If not, please give a small program that we can compile and run that *clearly* reproduces the problem.